# Why do we need to specify the lock for synchronized statements?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Given that there's only one lock for each instance of a class, then why doesn't Java just allow us to do this:

```
void method() {
    synchronized {
        // do something
    }

    // do other things
}
```

instead of this:

```
void method() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        // do something
    }

    // do other things
}
```

What's the purpose of specifying a lock? Does it make a difference if I choose one object as a lock over the other? Or could I just choose any random object?

EDIT:

It turned out that my comprehension of synchronized methods is wrong at the fundamental level.

I thought different synchronized methods or blocks are entirely independent of each other regardless of locks. Rather, all synchronized methods or blocks with the same lock can be accessed only by one thread, even if such synchronized methods/blocks are from different classes (the documentation should have emphasized this more: **ALL synced** methods/blocks, regardless of location, all that matters is the lock).

Comment: *Does it make a difference if I choose one object as a lock over the other?* yes, of course it makes a difference. If the goal is to use this as a lock, then use synchronized(this). That's what regular synchronized methods do: they synchronize on this.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you lock your own front door, or the neighbors front door? Of course it does. If you lock the wrong door, people can still enter your house.

Comment: It is just any random object, but it  important so you can have 2 seperate mutual exclusions, that's for instance, allow 2 threads to access 2 different methods but only one thread each method at once. Thus, both are technically synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given that there's only one lock for each instance of a class, then why doesn't Java just allow us to do this:
>
> ```
> void method() {
>     synchronized {
>         // do something
>     }
>
>     // do other things
> }
> ```

Although an intrinsic lock is provided with each instance,
that's not necessarily the "obvious" lock to use.

You're perhaps right that they could have provided `synchronized { ... }` as a shorthand for `synchronized (this) { ... }`.
I don't know why they didn't, but I never missed it.
But concurrent programming is tricky,
so making the lock object an explicit required parameter may make things clearer to readers, which is a good thing, as @ajb pointed out in a comment.
In any case, I don't think syntax is your main question, so let's move on.

> What's the purpose of specifying a lock?

Uhm, the lock is perhaps the single most important thing in the synchronization mechanism. The key point in synchronization is that only one thread can hold the same lock. Two threads holding different locks are not synchronized. So knowing what is the lock guarding the synchronization is crucial.

> Does it make a difference if I choose one object as a lock over the other?

I hope the previous section makes it clear that yes, you have to choose the object carefully. It has to be an object visible by all threads involved,
it has to be not null, and it has to be something that won't get reassigned during the period of synchronization.

> Or could I just choose any random object?

Certainly not. See the previous section.

To understand concurrency in Java, I recommend the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) by one of the authors of the API, or [Oracle's tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) on the subject.

Comment: I'm OK with them not providing `synchronized` as a shorthand for `synchronized(this)`, because (1) `synchronized(this)` isn't necessarily the most common usage, and (2) having the lock object be explicit makes things clearer for a reader.

Answer (score 1):

It's so you can lock on something completely different than `this`.

Remember how `Vector` is "thread-safe?" It's not quite that simple; each *call* is, but code like this isn't because it could have been updated between getting the size of the vector and getting the element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i) System.out.println(vector.get(i));
```

Since `Vector`, along with `Collections.synchronized*`, is synchronized with the older `synchronized` keyword, you can make that above code thread-safe by enclosing it all within a lock:

```
synchronized (vector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i) System.out.println(vector.get(i));
}
```

This could be in a method that isn't thread-safe, isn't synchronized, or uses `ReentrantLock`; locking the vector is separate from locking `this`.

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly makes a difference what object you use as a lock.  If you say

```
void method() {
    synchronized (x) {
        // do something
    }

    // do other things
}
```

Now, if one thread is executing the block and another tries to enter the block, if `x` is the same for both of them, then the second thread will have to wait.  But if `x` is different, the second thread can execute the block at the same time.  So, for example, if `method` is an instance method and you say

```
void method() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // do something
    }    
    // do other things
}
```

Now two threads running the method using the same object can't execute the block simultaneously, but two threads can still run the method on different objects without blocking each other.  This is what you'd want when you want to prevent simultaneous access to the instance variables in that object, but you don't have anything else you need to protect.  It's not a problem if two threads are accessing variables in two different objects.

But say the block of code is accessing a common resource, and you want to make sure all other threads are locked out of accessing that resource.  For example, you're accessing a database, and the block does a series of updates and you want to make sure they're done atomically, i.e. no other code should access the database while you're in between two updates.  Now `synchronized (this)` isn't good enough, because you could have the method running for two different objects but accessing the same database.  In this case, you'd need a lock that is the same for all objects that might access the same database.  Here, making the database object itself the lock would work.  Now no two threads can use `method` to enter this block at the same time, if they're working with the same database, even if the objects are different.

Answer (score 0):

In `synchronized (lock)..`, `lock` can be an object level lock or it can be class level lock.

- Example1 Class Level Lock:

  ```
  private static Object lock=new Object();
  synchronized (lock){
  //do Something
  }
  ```
- Example2 Object Level Lock:

  ```
  private Object lock=new Object();
  synchronized (lock){
  //do Something
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple objects b1/b2 needs to update concurrency

```
class A {
    private B b1, b2;
}
```

if you have only one lock say class A itself

```
synchronized (this) { ... }
```

then assume there are two threads are updating b1 and b2 in the same time, they will play one by one because **synchronized (this)**

but if you have two locks for b1 and b2

```
private Object lock1 = new Object, lock2 = new Object;
```

the two threads i've mentioned will play concurrently because **synchronized (lock1)** not affect **synchronized (lock2)**.sometimes means better performance.